# Are the amount of spell slots per caster level derived with math or decided arbitrarily?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-levels, spell-slots

I’m attempting to make a spreadsheet in google sheets that would function like an automatic character sheet. I know there a pages and charts in the phb concerting spell slot, but I was wondering how the math behind the multiclassing chart specifically worked in 5e. Other than the certain classes having their levels full, half, or 1/3 counted for caster level. I need the math formula for how each leveled slot is decided based on total caster level.